# Qt5 - QML: How to properly connect a ProgressBar with Button for long-running loop calculation

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5

I am connecting a `ProgressBar` to two `Buttons`. The `ProgressBar` will do a computation of a loop as soon as I push the button. The computation will be erased if I will push the other button. I still haven't implemented the `pause` button.

The print screen of what I am trying to achieve is below and in case needed the whole code of the **minimal verifiable example** is available [here](https://bitbucket.org/ERaggi/pbar/src/master/):

[image: pbar]

**The problem** is that as soon as I connect the `ProgressBar` with my `main.cpp` file I have a bunch of errors all that look like the following: 
`class ProgressDialog has no member named...`

[image: error]

code is below:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQuickView>
#include "progressbardialog.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQuickView view;
    ProgressBarDialog progressDialog;

    // One way but it does not work
    // engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("control", QVariant::fromValue(progressDialog.refModel()));
    // Another way but this also does not work
    view.setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("main.qml"));

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

**progressbardialog.h**

```
#ifndef PROGRESSBARDIALOG_H
#define PROGRESSBARDIALOG_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QFutureWatcher>

class ProgressBarDialog : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(float progress READ progress WRITE setProgress NOTIFY progressChanged)
public:
    ProgressBarDialog();
    float progress(int &iterator);
    // I will use this as a reference to pass to main.cpp using setContextProperty()
    QObject &refModel()
    {
        return m_Model;
    }

public Q_SLOTS:
    void startComputation();
    void cancelComputation();
signals:
    void progressChanged();
private:
    int m_progressValue;
    QObject m_Model;
    QFutureWatcher<void> m_futureWatcher;
};

#endif // PROGRESSBARDIALOG_H
```

**progressbardialog.cpp**

```
#include "progressbardialog.h"
#include <QtConcurrent/QtConcurrentMap>


ProgressBarDialog::ProgressBarDialog()
{}

void spin(int &iteration)
{
    const int work = 1000 * 1000 * 40;
    volatile int v = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < work; ++j)
        ++v;
}

float ProgressBarDialog::progress(int &iterator)
{
    (void) iterator;
    const int work = 1000 * 1000 * 40;
    volatile int v = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < work; ++j)
        ++v;
    emit progressChanged();
}

void ProgressBarDialog::startComputation()
{
    // Prepare the vector
    QVector<int> vector;
    for(int i = 0; i < 40; ++i)
        vector.append(i);
    const QFuture<void> future = QtConcurrent::map(vector, spin);
    m_futureWatcher.setFuture(future);
}

void ProgressBarDialog::cancelComputation()
{
    m_futureWatcher.cancel();
}
```

and finally the **main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.12                    // for the Item
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12           // for ApplicationWindow
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 440
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Progress Bar")
    ColumnLayout {
            spacing: 10
            width: parent.width
        GroupBox {
            id: box1
            title: "Start - Stop"
            font.pointSize: 20
            Layout.alignment: parent.width
            spacing: 10
            GridLayout {
                width: parent.width
                columns: 1
                RowLayout {
                    spacing: 200
                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                    Layout.fillHeight: false
                    Button {
                        id: buttonStart
                        text: "Start"
                        font.pointSize: 15
                        enabled: !progressDialog.active
                        onClicked: progressDialog.startComputation()
                    }
                    Button {
                        id: buttonFinish
                        text: "Finish"
                        font.pointSize: 15
                        enabled: progressDialog.cancelComputation()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        GroupBox {
            id: boxprogress
            title: "Progressbar"
            font.pointSize: 20
            Layout.alignment: parent.width
            spacing: 10
            GridLayout {
                width: parent.width
                columns: 1
                RowLayout {
                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                    Layout.fillHeight: false
                    ProgressBar {
                        id: progressbar_id
                        Layout.fillWidth: true
                        Layout.fillHeight: true
                        width: parent.width

                        // These are hard-coded values to confirm it is working
                        from: 0
                        to: 100
                        value: 5
                        onValueChanged: {
                            console.log("Progressbar value changed: ", progressbar_id.value)
                        }
                        onVisibleChanged: {
                            console.log("Progressbar visibility changed: ", progressbar_id.visible)
                        }
                    }
                    Connections {
                        target: progressDialog
                        onProgressChanged: progressbar_id.value = progress;
                    }
                    // This is working if clicking on the progressbar
                    MouseArea {
                        anchors.fill: parent
                        onClicked: progressbar_id.value += 5;
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
}
```

**What I tried so far** :

**1)** In order to prove myself that the `ProgressBarDialog` is correctly working I tried it before as a stand alone `main.qml` using hard-coded values (which I left in the code so you can see what I have done). But as soon as I started implementing it in the `.cpp` file and setting the `Q_PROPERTY` I received all the errors I posted on the second screenshot.

**2)** I am sure about the procedure taken so far because: a) According to the [official documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfuturewatcher.html) and from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12527141/how-can-i-use-a-qfuturewatcher-with-qtconcurrentrun-without-a-race-condition) because I will need to check the process of a long running operations; b) According to [QtConcurrent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrent.html#map) the process has a better possibility to be checked, and that is exactly what I did using `QtConcurrent::map()`

**3)** I am using the following statement in the **progressbardialog.h** to make sure that the object is correctly connected and listens to the `QML` file:

```
QObject &refModel()
{
    return m_Model;
}
```

But this did n't show and substancial improvements. Therefore digging more into the process I was thinking that it should have been the case to use `setContextProperty()`, whih cled me to the next point.

**4)** According to the [official documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlcontext.html#setContextProperty) and according to [this post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28924622/diiference-between-setcontextproperty-and-setproperty-of-object) I thought I would have fix the error, but it still remains.

I am runnign out of ideas and anyone who may have had this problem, please point to the right direction for a possible solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q_PROPERTY is designed to easier read/write/react to variable change (C++ side) on the QML side. To complete your example with variable read/write/notify add correct getter/setter (signal is already ok).

```
float progress();
void setProgress(float);
```

If you want to call a function from QML mark it Q_INVOKABLE instead.
Also what is the point of volatile in your code?

So to sum up, mark your iteration function as a Q_INVOKABLE. It will increment some internal progress value and then emit progressChanged(). This should cause QML side to update.

Comment: thank you very much for reading my question :) . Could you please explain better you answer putting in more detail what in the code should be modified?

Comment: I put some code in my repository: https://github.com/bialasjaroslaw/ProgressBar/tree/master

The only thing you need to add is to connect QFutureWatcher signal to something that will emit progressChanged():
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfuturewatcher.html#progressValueChanged

I will add it in couple minutes.

Comment: The `volatile` is there (I presume) so that the compiler doesn't optimize out the whole loop because otherwise it can tell the variable `v` is never actually used. The exact behavior will depend on compiler and optimization level, but it's safer to be sure. It's fairly common practice in benchmarks and test loops like this. A benchmark can return some pretty amazing results when the compiler got rid of all the actual code...  :-)

Comment: I prefer Chandler's trick with asm volatile :)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nXaxk27zwlk&feature=youtu.be&t=42m42s

Comment: @bialy, thank you very much, I see what you mean. it works, however I don't see you used the property `Q_INVOKABLE` in the example

Comment: @MaximPaperno, yes exactly, I was doing some benchmark test on a long running cycle but needed to implement it in `QML`. The `volatile` I used to be safer than sure :)

Comment: @Emanuele `Q_INVOKABLE` is used to mark a function as a callable from QML context. Other way is to implement is as a slot (which I did in this case).
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-exposecppattributes.html